# How to use STM32F1 ADC if input is more than 3.3V?

Tags: stm32, adc

[Datasheet of STM32F103X8](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfZZza-XTgtBiAVMjI_kxIcL8H2rAhbR/view?usp=sharing)

I found the sensor output a voltage ranged 0~5V, which is higher than the ADC port can tolerate with (in STM32F1XX datasheet all ADC ports can only tolerate 3.3V).

How to make it accessible to input 0~5V ,without destroying MCU and, not losing too much accuracy of analog voltage input?

[Datasheet of sensor](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10on0DoBcFsuWJd3-NnAaytTSXNMnMFhI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use a voltage divider circuit to scale down the voltage from 0-5V to within the range that the ADC port can tolerate (0-3.3V).

Comment: @liaifat85 For example tandem resistors voltage divider?

Comment: To help get an answer can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/707075/edit) the question and include a link to the datasheet for the sensor. Depending upon the output impedance of the sensor may affect how a voltage divider with resistors can be achieved.

Comment: The link to the _datasheet of sensor_ which has been added to the question is ``https://file///C:/Users/Dell2/Desktop/TSW-30.pdf``. I.e. a link to a file on your PC and therefore not visible to others.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Thanks...ehh but how to upload file in the question though?

Comment: @ssss The datasheet links points to a file on your hard drive.

Comment: Both links are the same and to a local resource not available to us.  Please fix the links or provide correct part numbers and manufacturer so we can fix the links.

Comment: Alright..I got attaching personal file by sharing with cloud drive eventually.

Comment: You have to follow the voltage divider rule to make a voltage divider circuit with two resistors.  Vout=Vin*R2/(R1+R2). In your case, Vin=5V and Vout=3.3V. You can select the values of R1 and R2 according to this formula. Here is more about voltage divider circuit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGXdi7XcQ